# Can I add nested root nodes with FOR JSON?

Tags: json, sql-server

I know how to get Json out of SQL Server, including a root node.

```sql
SELECT 'bar' AS [foo]
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('items');
```

yields

```json
{
    "items": [
        {"foo": "bar"}
    ]
}
```

But I want another root node to wrap `items`, because I have to conform to a prescribed format that effectively has a nested root node.

```json
{
    "baz": {
        "items": [
            {"foo": "bar"}
        ]
    }
}
```

How do I achieve this? Is the only way using a sub-select?

Using

```sql
SELECT
  (
    SELECT 'bar' AS [foo]
    FOR JSON PATH, ROOT ('items')
  ) AS [baz]
FOR JSON PATH;
```

yields

```json
[
  {
    "baz": {
      "items": [
        {"foo": "bar"}
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

after which I can strip the outer brackets. *(Note: from the current answer, I can specify `WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` to do so).*

Is there another, easier way to achieve this? Especially without the sub-select?

Answer (score 2):

There is easier than yours. With [WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/remove-square-brackets-from-json-without-array-wrapper-option?view=sql-server-2017) there is no need to strip outer brackets:

```
SELECT
  (
    SELECT 'bar' AS [foo]
    FOR JSON PATH, ROOT ('items')
  ) AS [baz]
FOR JSON PATH,WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

Comment: But is there a way to do this without the sub-select?